# add a new column to a pandas dataframe based on groupby value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
  date                value
1/1/2017               -3
1/1/2017               -1 
1/1/2017                5 
1/2/2017                4
1/2/2017                9
1/2/2017               -1
```

what I want to do is to add an additional column, `is_min` that will get `1` if the value is minimal for this date, else `0`.

so the result should be:

```
 date                 value            is_min
1/1/2017               -3                1
1/1/2017               -1                0 
1/1/2017                5                0 
1/2/2017                4                0
1/2/2017                9                0 
1/2/2017               -1                1
```

I tried things like

```
df['is_min']=df['value']==df.groupby('date')['value'].min()
```

but, of course, the length of `df['value']` and  `df.groupby('date')['value'].min()` don't match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for find minimal index in `group`, then test membership by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df['is_min'] = df.index.isin(df.groupby('date')['value'].idxmin()).astype(int)
print (df)
       date  value  is_min
0  1/1/2017     -3       1
1  1/1/2017     -1       0
2  1/1/2017      5       0
3  1/2/2017      4       0
4  1/2/2017      9       0
5  1/2/2017     -1       1
```

---

```
df['is_min'] = 0
df.loc[df.index.isin(df.groupby('date')['value'].idxmin()), 'is_min'] = 1
print (df)
       date  value  is_min
0  1/1/2017     -3       1
1  1/1/2017     -1       0
2  1/1/2017      5       0
3  1/2/2017      4       0
4  1/2/2017      9       0
5  1/2/2017     -1       1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Glad can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `transform()` method of a GroupBy object:

```
df['ismin'] = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform(lambda x: x == np.min(x))
```

It returns a DataFrame the full size of the original with a transformation function applied. 
Note that I have subset on the 'value' column before doing the transformation, since `transform()` applies on on the full column set of the grouped object.

Comment: very interesting and it actually works. My question is what is `x` in your lambda expression?  Is it the group, or each element in the group?

Comment: `transform()` takes a function as an argument that expects a dataframe, thus `x` in this case is the grouped dataframe produced for each of your groups.
It will only contain one column: `value`, since it has been sliced in the step before.